# Cut line at intersection using Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I'm trying to cut a line at the intersection, if a line crosses another line within a single multilinestring then and the end of the line is below a maximum distance threshold then it swaps the end of the line co ordinates to the intersection. As shown in this image.

[image: I am trying to basically create this image using shapely.]

The code I have so far is:

```
def trim_lines_to_intersection(lines, MAX_DIST):
'''If a road intersects with another road, end the road at the intersection
if the distance between the endpoint of the line and the intersection is less than
MAX_DIST'''

# initialize trimmed lines with list of original lines
#trimmed_lines = [line for line in lines]
trimmed_lines = [LineString(array) for array in lines]
#trimming_points = vertices_from_lines(trimmed_lines)
for i, line in enumerate(trimmed_lines):
    for q in [-1]:
        endpoint = Point(line.coords[q])

for road1, road2 in itertools.combinations(trimmed_lines, 2):
    x = road1.intersection(road2)
    if x.distance(endpoint) < MAX_DIST:
        Point(endpoint.coords[q]) = x
return trimmed_lines
```

Testing:

`coords_SE = [((5, 5), (20, 5)), ((10, 10), (10, 0)), ((15,0), (15,10))]
lines_SE = MultiLineString(coords_SE)

test  = trim_lines_to_intersection(lines_SE, 6)`

The error I am receiving is: SyntaxError: can't assign to function call.